# Output load pull matching in power amplifier to ensure maximum output power

Tags: radio

Maximizing the output power of a power amplifier does not follow the conjugate matching rule for maximum power transfer. Does that mean that the amplifier will experience reflection? This doesn't seem to make sense but then how can one explain that load pull matching? (Ideally the amplifier would want to see an impedance = VDD/IDD, in the absence of any reactance.)

Comment: This would be more appropriate for electronics stack exchange not signal processing

Comment: Ca you please send me the corresponding link? Thank you

Comment: _"Ideally the amplifier would want to see an impedance = VDD/IDD, in the absence of any reactance"_- why?

Answer (score 0):

Load pull is used because it is difficult to model the large signal behavior of the transistors. Linear models can be used to calculate the conjugate match, but that would only be valid if transistors were linear devices. Load pull  finds the best match for the actual circuit operating at actual power out.

Comment: So how does the VSWR at the output  look like in case of load pull matching vs conjugate matching?

Comment: The output impedance of the amplifier varies as the output signal amplitude varies. So, (for example) conjugate matching the output impedance at 1mW output will result in a poor VSWR at 1 watt output. Using the load pull match (at one watt) will improve that VSWR at 1 watt.  That load pull match will probably not be optimum  if you are outputting only a milliwatt.

Comment: So why would the VSWR be good at approx. 1 watt when a load pull match is used? I mean since it is conjugate matching that usually ensures good VSWR? (I know it wouldn't ensure max. possible power or P1 dB)

Comment: Well, the VSWR would not be the very best at a different signal level than you did the load pull at.  However, you are probably more interested in good matching at high powers than at low powers, so you make it better at high power.